# Need time stamps for two separate sheets in google spreadsheet within same custom script

Tags: date, time, google-sheets

I have a document in Google Sheets (I work in healthcare simulation) that has two separate sheets (tabs) within the master. One tab is MAR, the other is VITALS. I need each one to run from within the same script and not interfere with each other. I can only get one to work, not the other.

I will post each one below (you will be able to see that when one works, the other does not but each WILL work when the other is //rem'd out).

I am not sure which variables to change to have them coexist and work together. I know I must be missing something simple. ***THANK YOU*** in advance!

MAR TIME STAMP

```
function onEdit() {
  var x = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( x.getName() == "MAR" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var y = x.getActiveCell();
    if( y.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = y.offset(0,1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

VITALS TIME STAMP

```
function onEdit() {
  var x = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( x.getName() == "Vitals" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var y = x.getActiveCell();
    if( y.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = y.offset(0,1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
 function onEdit() {
  var x = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( x.getName() == "MAR" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var y = x.getActiveCell();
    if( y.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = y.offset(0,1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
if( x.getName() == "Vitals" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var y = x.getActiveCell();
    if( y.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = y.offset(0,1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You sir are a steely-eyed missile man! I cannot thank you and everyone else here enough!

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sh, sheets, cols, sheetInd, o;
sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
sheets = ["MAR", "Vitals"]
cols = [4, 1]
sheetInd = sheets.indexOf(sh.getName())
if(sheetInd == -1 || cols[sheetInd !== e.range.columnStart]) return;
o = e.range.offset(0, 1)
if(!o.getValue()) o.setValue(new Date())
}
```

Comment: The initial answer works perfectly, but if I try running this script, I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "DateTimeStamps")...are there potential pitfalls using one script over the other? I'm just trying to think ahead...thank you for you help!!

Comment: This script uses an event object that is 'formed' when the spreadsheet is edited. You can not run this script manually (by clicking the 'play' button in the script editor. Instead, you have to go back to your sheet and edit the designated columns. Then see if the date appears.

Comment: Some info you might find interesting: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: Reading up on it now...thank you! I want to learn everything I can to get better with GS/JS and I'm not sure where to start. You guys really are life savers